# How to show exactly what I type

Tags: code

I want to put code of my calculation in computer algebra systems in my PDF file. If I just paste the code in the `.tex` file, it does not get shown correctly in the PDF file: I would need to change `x^32` to `x^{32}` for example. For practical purposes, I want to keep the code as it is. So I'd like to know if there is a way to make the PDF file show exactly what I type.

Comment: There are two major syntax highlighting packages, `listings` and `minted`, if you don't need any fancy formatting or syntax highlighting, there is the `verbatim` environment in the LaTeX kernel. If it's supposed to be displayed inline, you can use the `\verb` macro (again, in the kernel), or similar macros from one of the above packages.

Comment: Could you please show an example of what you'd like to input along with the expected output?

Comment: For LaTeX code, one can use the verbatim environment or \verb.